# Why does "while....in" not remove the "€" from string?

Tags: python, string, web-scraping, while-loop

I came across a (for me and my little experience) weird issue.

I scrape a list that looks like this after being scraped and a little bit cleaned:

```
['[', '€23600', '€7600', '€3600', '€1600', '€800', '€400']
```

The list can contain €, $ or £ as currency. I want to get rid of the currency, so I use(d)

```
    while "€" in pricemoney: pricemoney.remove("€")
    while "£" in pricemoney: pricemoney.remove("£")
    while "$" in pricemoney: pricemoney.remove("$")
```

which works for $ and £, but not for €.
pricemoney is the variable that contains the list.
I tried to check if € is maybe a different symbol than the one on the normal keybord, but it *seems* to be the same

I switched to

```
pricemoney = [re.sub(r'\D(?=\d+)', "", i) for i in pricemoney]
```

which gets rid of all th currencys in one go (and thus is the better way anyway) but I still can't figure out why the "€" was not catched with the while statement?

Answer (score 2):

The code `while "€" in pricemoney: pricemoney.remove("€")` checks if the string "€" is inside the list `pricemoney`. What it means is that it will remove any string equals to "€" but not starts with. Same thing applies to the other two symbols you mentioned.

To see that, try to run the following commands and see that it will only remove the first element:

```
pricemoney = ['€', '€2000']
while "€" in pricemoney: pricemoney.remove("€")


pricemoney = ['$', '$2000']
while "$" in pricemoney: pricemoney.remove("$")
```

Comment: Thanks! So the reason while the other two worked were probably because there was a whitespace in front of them or something? Because the while "£" in pricemoney: pricemoney.remove("£") - worked?

Comment: If you try to execute `while "$" in pricemoney: pricemoney.remove("$")` for `['[', '$23600', '$3600', '$3600', '$1600', '$800', '$400']`,  you will see that it does not work! When you saw it work, was pricemoney = `['$', '€23600', '€7600', '€3600', '€1600', '€800', '€400']`?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly a regex replacement might be best here:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*
import re

inp = ['[', '€23600', '€7600', '€3600', '€1600', '€800', '€400']
output = [re.sub(r'[€£$](\d+)', r'\1', x) for x in inp]
print(output)  # ['[', '23600', '7600', '3600', '1600', '800', '400']
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! I already did a regex replacement (figured it out after some tinkering, *dough* - is the one I used ok? - its in the question) but I still can't figure out why the € did not get catched previously?

Comment: @Phil You may need to declare your Python script as using UTF-8.